# SSRS Multi Column Report - Repeat Group Headers After Column Break

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I would like a report that has a list of data, and I would like this data in two columns.  Some of this data will span across 60+ pages.  There are groups within this data, and each level of grouping has a header.

I would like the header to appear at the top of each column, not just on the new page as detailed here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627566(v=sql.100).aspx

Where is the setting to say "Repeat Group Header at the top of each Column"?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the header text row and "Insert Row Above", you should be able to see the header repeat with each group.  If you have selected the row and "Inserted Row - Outside Group", the value header will only show once.

Comment: Thanks Daryl, but I'm looking to have it repeat at the top of the second column on the page as well. Does this approach achieve this?

Comment: If you add an outside group to the grouping that creates the second column than, yes it should.  If you are still experiancing problems, post a pic of your report layout from both designer and preview to highlight where its not working.